# PrimeFaces Notify

Tags: primefaces, websocket, atmosphere

I'm trying to implement the PrimeFaces notify examples located [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml).  I've implemented the exact same code as shown in the linked example but every time I try to run it I get the following error in the web console.

```
Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending
push.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.1:1 GET http://localhost:8080/Notify/primepush/notify?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&…ng&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-atmo-protocol=true&_=1426529434646 404 (Not Found)
```

I've satisfied all of the dependencies for primefaces 5.1 and jsf 2.2.6.  I'm really stuck on this one.  I can't quite figure out what it is I'm missing.  Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Please post your code here, client side and server side.

Comment: And what server/container and did you try different clients?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here.

include this to your .xhtml file between ui:define and script tags

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
     <script>
            function doGrowling(){
                growlUi.renderMessage({summary: "Summary goes here", detail: "Detail goes here", severity: 0});
            }
        </script>
</ui:define>
```

After that execute that javascript function from your backing bean like this:

```
public void executeGrowlMessage(){
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("doGrowling();");
}
```